# Place a View at Bottom in ScrollView/LinearLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

I've just started with Android and was developing my first app that includes a Login Screen.

Initially, I had used `RelativeLayout` and `AdView` or any other View was getting correctly placed to the bottom of the parent using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

Then, while reading about Material Guidelines, I was referring to a XML that used `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView`. Now I can't place my `AdView` to the bottom most position (try importing this XML to your Android Studio). Searching for answers here, I also placed it inside `RelativeLayout` and used `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` again but no success. I know Android users have played with all this and I hope they can help me.

**So, listing my basic questions as:**

- ***Can you tell me the actual use the OP has used `ScrollView` for Login Screen Activity? If you know how to handle UI of the activity, can you just post two or more lines of any tip on what should I use? Any tip would be highly appreciated.***
- ***Main Question - So, how do I place `AdView` to the bottom? An explanation would be appreciated.***

Thanks. :)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#FFB74D">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:backgroundTintMode="src_atop">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Gyaanify"
                android:textSize="55sp"
                android:textColor="#FF3D00"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:fontFamily="cursive"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/etUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:onClick="OnLogin"
            android:background="#EF6C00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No account yet? Create one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Register @ Gyaanify"
            android:onClick="OnRegister"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#EF6C00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you use `ScrollView` which should fill the entire screen, it should have `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"` attributes. This is true in you code. But the inner `LinearLayout` should have `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"`which makes sense if you think of it.

Now, to place the `AdView` at the bottom of the screen and to have all the content scroll above it, you need the following layout structure:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- all your content here -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Setting the `ScrollView` weight to 1 will make sure your AdView is stick to the bottom.